# WCF routing script

Tags: jquery, wcf, routes

I found 2 examples of code for wcf services.

1. implements comsuming a wcf service from js cliet side.
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call
2. implements a routing mechanism to wrap existing service functionality and redirect the call to another address.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx

is there an existing example that does both routing and ajax consumer?

Comment: WCF Routing is SOAP-based - so if you're looking for a combination of WCF REST and Routing Service, you're probably not going to find it as SOAP and REST are pretty much on opposite sides of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WCF Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422.aspx) is SOAP-based - so if you're looking for a combination of WCF REST and Routing Service, you're probably not going to find it as SOAP and REST are pretty much on opposite sides of the spectrum.

Comment: And what about non "REST" services, can they provide javascript access? can I do both browser-consuming and server ridirecting?

Comment: also tried routing with a message inspector, but this also doesnt work with ajax...